# Electron App on Heroku and error related to libpng12.so.0:

Tags: linux, heroku, electron, apt, libpng

On Heroku 18 I have an error:

```
electron:stderr /app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared
libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried different stacks on heroku: 16 and 18
haven't tried 14 because it is marked as deprecated (EOL)
on heroku 16 I have different errors also related to "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Heroku Apt File

```
xvfb
x11-xkb-utils
xfonts-100dpi
xfonts-75dpi
xfonts-scalable
xfonts-cyrillic
libxfont1
libnotify4
libxss1
libpng-dev
libpng12-0
libpng12-dev
```

Successfull deploy of electron app on heroku

Comment: Sorry if I don't get it, but why would you want to deploy a desktop application, which an Electron app is, to Heroku?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner This app uses nightmare which depends on electron. It is not actually a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is Heroku is a server based cli-less system so Electron won't host.
You could always try converting stuff to run on puppeteer (headless mode) which runs well (at least for my web scraping).
This probably isn't what you want to hear but I have tried for a long time and can't get Electron to run on heroku.